# Design algorithm to solve penguins marching problem

Tags: algorithm

It is well known that penguins march. In one particular colony, any two penguins have grown to establish a marching order between them: one of them is willing to follow the other but not the other way around. Given a group of penguins, can you design an algorithm that lines them up such that every penguin is willing to follow the one immediately in front of it?

My question is, what if we have 3 penguins A, B, and C, then A is willing to follow B, B is willing to follow C and C is willing to follow A, such that a cycle is created, so it's impossible to line them up. 
So the idea here is I'm thinking if the group of penguins forms a graph, then we may able to use Dijkstra’s Algorithm for adjacency list representation to lines all penguins up? But what is the condition of the graph, it must has no cycle or direct? 
Stuck on this question for awhile, any hint will be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at *topological sorting*. Penguins are *nodes*; if penguin `A` is willing to follow `B` then draw a *directed edge* from `A` to `B`. Finally, sort the graph topologicaly, if it's possible, the order of nodes is a possible line of penguins https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have been thinking topological sorting initially, but since the question mentions given a group of penguins, I thought it's given a graph that already in some certain condition, such it has cycle or it's direct acyclic. But what you remind me that my assignment only ask to design an algorithm can be use either the pseudocode or precise description in words
of the algorithm. So I can actually describe in words, say the group of penguins form a graph which has directed edge from A to B and so on, then using topological sorting algorithm to sort the graph?

Comment: for me it seems enough to mention graph creation and topological sorting; may be a reference for a topological sorting algorithm (say, *Kahn's algorithm*) will may your assignment better.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Create a *Directed Graph* with

- Nodes: Penguins (`A`, `B`, `C`, ...)
- Edges: between nodes `X` and `Y` if and only if penguin `X` is willing to follow `Y`

Then (try to) *sort* the graph *topologically*; if it's possible, the order of *nodes* (i.e. penguins) gives you a required line of penguins; is the graph can't be sorted topologically (e.g. if graph has a *cycle*), no such line exists.

**Edit:** If `A` should *immediately* follow `B` so (`A, C, B`) is not a valid line (`A` follows `B`, however, not *immediately*), but (`A, B, C`) is, then the problem is easier.

Create the *Directed Graph* and check if it's a set of *lines*, e.g.:

```
A -> B -> C
D -> E
F
...
P -> Q -> R -> S -> T
...
X -> Y -> Z
```

If it is, combine these lines in arbitrary order (say, `A, B, C, D, E, ..., Z`); if not the solution *doesn't exist*. Note, that we can't have any *ramification*:

```
A -> B
A -> C
```

means that `A` is willing to imediately follow *both* `B` and `C` which is *impossible*, and

```
A -> B
C -> B
```

means that *both* `A` and `C` are willing to immediately follow `B` which is *impossible* as well.

**Edit 2:** if each penguin has a set of other penguins he is willing to follow, e.g.

```
  A: {B, C, D}  #  A is ready to immediately follow B, C or D
  B: {A, C}     #  B wants to immediately follow A or C
  C: {B, D}     #  C is ready to be just after B or D
  D: {}         #  D doesn't want to follow anyone
```

and the solution can be `C, B, A, D` (`D` leads the line, followed by `A`) then we should provide a path which visits each node exactly once. This is *Hamiltonian Path* and the task is *NP-Complete*

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which is specifically about a situation where topological sorting is impossible (because the graph contains a cycle). (Did you read the whole question before writing this answer?)

Answer (score 0):

This is [the Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem). It's NP-hard, so no efficient algorithm is known (or believed to exist) in the general case. Of course, you can solve it *inefficiently* by simply trying all possible paths using depth-first search.